# Change color scheme on komodo edit

Tags: komodo, komodoedit

I am trying to change the color scheme in Komodo Edit, version 6. I am running Windows 7.

I put the .ksf file in the /schemes folder, Now what?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just drag and drop the ksf file on the Komodo editor.

Comment: This doesn't work for Komodo 7.0. All I get is an access denied icon.

Comment: @gotnull - Then you probably don't have access to the filesystem and/or where the komodo ksf file will be located. I was able to do as mLar stated - without a hiccup.